# Sorting a WMI-result in C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I want to check the succesed last windows update. In principle, this works .
The problem is, that the date is not right. I think I can solve the problem if sorting the result by last date and use desc / asc. I don' know how to do this. If I use MySQL I could use "... order by column desc / asc", but it seems this does not work with C# / WMI. Could anyone give me a help please.That's my code so far:

```
try
{
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering");
    using (ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = searcher.Get())
    {
        ManagementObject managementObject = managementObjectCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().First();
        string stringDate = managementObject["InstalledOn"].ToString();
        string format = "M/d/yyyy";
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DateTimeOffset result = new DateTimeOffset();
        result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(stringDate, format, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
        systemLastWindowsUpdate = result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Problem in Windows Update");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty inefficiently written, not the least of your problems being that you never dispose the searcher object which holds OS handles. That said, the answer to your question is simply: if you want the last date, simply look at all of them and pick the maximum.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

using var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering");
using var managementObjectCollection = searcher.Get();

var maxDate = managementObjectCollection.OfType<ManagementObject>().Max(w => DateTime.Parse((string)w["InstalledOn"]));
Console.WriteLine(maxDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but didn't work. I think this is, because I have german windows. Thats the reason, why I reformat the date.

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't mean anything. And you don't need to "reformat" the date, a `DateTime` is a `DateTime` no matter the locale. In fact, because you know you use a different format, you should be avoiding text formats for your date like the plague, not doubling down on them.